# In Python using Pandas, is it possible to read 4B rows chunkwise and filter each chuck against a 30M row dataframe already in memory?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, large-data

Have a 4B row table in Oracle and a 30M row CSV, both tables share 2 columns on which I want to filter the large table using the smaller table. Due to security restrictions, I cannot load the 30M row CSV into Oracle and run a single join which would be ideal. I have also tried to use SAS Enterprise Guide for this process, but it seems to choke on the large join and fails to return before the connection to the Oracle table times out.

Python seems to be a possible solution, but the 4B row table will not fit into memory, even when reducing to the 6 columns I need (6 strings each under 25 chars). Ideally, I'd like to do the following:

```
csv_df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
result_df = (empty dataframe)
df_chunks = pd.read_sql(sql_query, con, chunksize = 10000000)
    for df_chunk in df_chunks:
      # convert chunk to dataframe
      # join chunk_dataframe to csv_df to get a filtered result
      # concatenate filtered result to result_df
```

The dataframe result_df will then be the set of all filtered rows from the 4B row Oracle table.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
csv_df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
result_df = (empty dataframe)
df_chunks = pd.read_sql(sql_query, con, chunksize = 10000000)
chunk_list = []
for df_chunk in df_chunks:
    result = pd.merge(df_chunk, csv_df, on=['XXX'])
    chunk_list.append(result)
result_df = pd.concat(chunk_list)
```

Comment: Obviously, with 4B rows against 30M and 10M chunks, this is going to take a while. However, this does appear to be running through the chunks correctly. I am very encouraged and thank you for your help. Will update once I get my results.

Comment: Worked perfectly and even allowed me to overcome having my Oracle connection dropped for being connected for too long! Thanks for the assist!